# Fourier Transform of $\cos x$ on finite interval

Tags: fourier-transform

Let $f(x)=\cos x$ for $-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$, and $0$ everywhere else.

Then $\tilde f(\omega)$ becomes
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos (x) e^{-i \omega x} dx=\frac{2\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}\omega)}{1-\omega^2}$$

---

There are just some confusion I got for this kind of functions

If we consider the Fourier transform of $f''(x)=- \cos x$ for $-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$, and $0$ everywhere else. Assuming we can even take the derivatives of such function (defined only on an open interval) to begin with, the Fourier transform of $f''$ becomes $$\frac{-\omega^22\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}\omega)}{1-\omega^2}$$
So the Fourier transform of $\cos x$ differs by a factor of $\omega^2$, but we have defined our Fourier transform to be unique? Are those 2 functions the same after inverse Fourier transform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be defined as

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\cos(x)&|x|\le \pi/2\\\\0&,|x|\ge\pi/2\end{cases}$$

We can write $f(x)=\cos(x)\text{rect}(x/\pi)$ in terms of the rectangular function

$$\text{rect}(x)=\begin{cases}
1&, |x|<1/2\\\\0&,|x|>1/2
\end{cases}$$

Then, we have in distribution

$$f'(x)=-\sin(x)\text{rect}(x/\pi) $$

and

$$f''(x)=-\cos(x)\text{rect}(x/\pi)+\delta(x-\pi/2)+\delta(x+\pi/2)$$

So, the Fourier Transform of $f''(x)$ is

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{f''\}(\omega)&=\mathscr{F}\{-f\}+e^{-i\omega \pi/2}+e^{i\omega \pi/2}\\\\
&=-\frac{2\cos(\omega \pi/2)}{1-\omega^2}+2\cos(\omega \pi/2)\\\\
&=-\frac{2\omega^2 \cos(\omega \pi/2)}{1-\omega^2}\\\\
&=-\omega^2 \mathscr{F}\{f\}(\omega)
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Hi, could you please explain how we get the derivatives (I assume by product rule) for $f’$ and $f’’$?

Comment: Yes, use the product rule.

Comment: What is the derivative of $rect(x/\pi)$?

Comment: $$\text{rect}'(x/\pi)=\delta(x+\pi/2)-\delta(x-\pi/2)$$

Comment: Thanks! That clears everything up

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.